# How to populate a SFMC/ExactTarget Data Extension from an external source like Hive/Cassandra/S3?

Tags: email, import, insert, marketing-cloud

I am completely new to ExactTarget/SFMC, and am learning as I go along. There might be a use case where we aggregate events in Hive and store it in Hive tables or in Cassandra or in S3 buckets (we're not yet sure of that yet), and then populate these aggregated values in SFMC for email campaigns.

Is there a way we can write to SFMC data extensions from Hive/Cassandra/S3?